# Making a smile/horseshoe/half circle with rounded edges in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm doing some CSS animations with a baby's animated face, and I'm trying to create the mouth as a specific smile shape.
The shape I need looks like this. Take note of the top left and right edges, which are rounded:

[image: Smile]

You can see the closest I've gotten here. The only thing missing is the rounded top left and right edges.

```css
.half-circle {
  height:150px;
  width: 75px;
  border-radius: 150px 0 0 150px;
  border-top: 20px solid #000;
  border-left: 20px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #000;
  transform: translate(100px) rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="half-circle"></div>
```

*Edit The submitted answers so far are not good enough so I unfortunately had to use a bitmap instead. If someone finds a better solution in the future, please provide an answer and I'll mark it as accepted if it works adequately.

Comment: How about putting two more elements - small circles - on the end? Not the cleanest way though...

Comment: @Flink nice idea, I hadn't thought of that, it might work, I'll try it out tomorrow while I wait for any other suggestions, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Flink suggested adding circles in a comment so I tried it, and while not perfect it might be the best option. I edited the fiddle below with the circles. If someone has a better alternative or a way to do this better, then please let me know/post an answer:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/renxp2w4/2/)

```css
.half-circle {
    height:150px;
    width: 75px;
    border-radius: 150px 0 0 150px;
    border-top: 20px solid #000;
    border-left: 20px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #000;
    transform: translate(100px) rotate(-90deg);
    position: relative;
}
.border-circle {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.left-circle {
  right: -8px;
  top: -20px;
}
.right-circle {
  bottom: -20px;
  right: -8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="half-circle">
  <div class="border-circle left-circle"></div>
  <div class="border-circle right-circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```css
.half-circle {
    height:150px;
    width: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 150px 0 0 150px;
    border-top: 20px solid #000;
    border-left: 20px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #000;
    transform: translate(100px) rotate(-90deg);
}
.half-circle:before, .half-circle:after{
    content: "";
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 99%;
    top: -20px;
    background: #000;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.half-circle:after{
  bottom:-20px;
  top: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="half-circle"></div>
```

[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/renxp2w4/15/)

Answer (score 1):

By changing the `0 0` in `border-radius`, I was able to round the outer
sides of the half circle. I will edit if/when I figure out the
insides.

**Note**: I understand this isn't the full answer but it might get you on the right track.

```css
.half-circle {
    height:150px;
    width: 75px;
    border-radius: 150px  20px 20px 150px ;
    border-top: 20px solid #000;
    border-left: 20px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #000;
    transform: translate(100px) rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="half-circle"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've already tried doing this, I couldn't find a way to change how the inner corners were shaped without adding another border. If you can figure out a way to make it work though, then all the power to you!

Comment: @AlexPodworny I think your solution with the circles is probably best, for accomplishing the task you want.